# Adding Margins on Blogger

Tags: css, templates, blogger

I want to seperate "TR" and "EN" sections on my navigation bar. Here is problematic one:

http://en.ahmetvarlik.com/

TR and EN tabs are too close each other in this website. I want to arrange these like this:

[Sample Align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsQCm.jpg)

In first website (en.ahmetvarlik.com), I added different codes in "navibar" section. I also gave this section font-size, text-align , but I could not give margins and text-color.
Can anyone help me?

Codes:
First website (en.ahmetvarlik.com):

```
a.navitabs, a.navitabs:link, a.navitabs:visited {display:inline-block !important; width:20x; height:25px; margin: 0 10px 0 10px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px; color: #616161 !important; line-height:25px; overflow:hidden; float:none;}

a.navitabs:hover {color: #000000;}
#navibar {width:200px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; color: #616161 !important; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px; float:none;}


<b:widget id='HTML3' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'>
 <b:widget-settings>
   <b:widget-setting name='content'>&lt;!-- Navigation tabs start --&gt;
&lt;div id=&#39;navibar&#39;&gt;
&lt;script language=&quot;javascript&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
document.write (&quot;&lt;a href=&quot; + window.location.protocol + &quot;//&quot; + &quot;www.ahmetvarlik.com&quot; + window.location.pathname + &quot;&gt;  TR  &lt;/a&gt;&quot;); 
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script language=&quot;javascript&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt; 
document.write (&quot;&lt;a href=&quot; + window.location.protocol + &quot;//&quot; + &quot;en.ahmetvarlik.com&quot; + window.location.pathname + &quot;&gt;  EN  &lt;/a&gt;&quot;); 
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;!-- Navigation tabs end --&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</b:widget-setting>
```

Codes of sample image :

```
a.navitabs, a.navitabs:link, a.navitabs:visited {display:inline-block !important; width:20x; height:25px; margin: 0 10px 0 10px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px; color: #616161; line-height:25px; overflow:hidden; float:none;}

a.navitabs:hover {color: #000000;}
#navibar {width:200px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}

<!--Navigation page element starts -->
<div id='navibar-wrapper'> 
<b:section class='navibar_section' id='navibar_section' showaddelement='yes'>


<b:widget id='HTML3' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'>
 <b:widget-settings>
   <b:widget-setting name='content'>&lt;!-- Navigation tabs start --&gt;
&lt;div id=&#39;navibar&#39;&gt;
&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.ahmetvarlik.com/&quot; class=&quot;navitabs&quot; title=&gt;TR&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;a href=&quot;SOON!&quot; class=&quot;navitabs&quot; title=&gt;EN&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;!-- Navigation tabs end --&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</b:widget-setting>
 </b:widget-settings>
 <b:includable id='main'>
<!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
<h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
</b:if>
<div class='widget-content'>
<data:content/>
</div>



<b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section> 
</div> 
<div style='clear: both;'/>
<!--Navigation page element ends -->
```

Comment: Please add code that you've tried so far.

Comment: I editted my question.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm trying to set margins on your div and links it works as intended, I see no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I just added:

```
#navibar a { color: #616161 !important; margin: 0 10px 0 10px;}
```

but `#navibar a:hover { color: #000000;}` not working.